# MySql to text with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, html-table

I have a problem. I Googled about it but I couldn't find the answer. So, I have a website where users can add their creations. This creations are going in a MySql table. Now, I want to take data from this table and to send it to a .txt file, but, I want to save it in a text file with the title that it have in the table. My mysql table has 4 columns:

```
creations, title, user and categories.
```

I want to save each row from table in a separate text file with the title from the title column. Or, when user click on post a creation to not send it to database but to send it directly to a text file with the title that they add.

---

This is postcreations.php

```
if ($_POST['posteaza']) {
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", $uname, $password,$database) or die (" nu ma pot conecta");
    mysqli_query($con,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS postest (id int(255) NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
    continut varchar(10000000),
    titlul varchar(200),
    categorie varchar(200),
    user varchar(30))") or die (" nu pot crea");
    $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(stripslashes($_POST['continut']))); 
    $titlul = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(stripslashes($_POST['titlul']))); 
    $categorie=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(stripslashes($_POST['categorii'])));
    $user=$_POST['username'];
    if($text!=NULL && $titlul!=NULL)
   mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO postest(continut,titlul,categorie,user)  VALUES ('$text','$titlul','$categorie','$username')") or die ('Error updating database');
```

And this is how I'm taking everything out:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost",$name,$password,$database) or die("Nu se poate deschide baza de date");
$query = "SELECT * FROM postest1"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results


 echo "<table><tr><td>" . $row['titlul'].", de ".$row['user']."</td><td></table>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
```

Comment: Can you post the code of what you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

Here ye' go

```
 <?php 
       //Connect to database then insert following
        $result = mysqli_query($CONN, "SELECT creations, title, user, categories FROM people WHERE id = '42'");
        if (!$result) {
                  echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysqli_error();
                  exit;
        }
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
              $fp = fopen($row["title"].'.txt', 'w');
              fwrite($fp, "creation:".$row["creations"].",title:".$row["title"].",user:".$row["user"].",catagories:".$row["catagories"]);
              fclose($fp);
        }
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated, you should use mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: That's true... but the reason its deprecated is due to sql injection. The above code doesn't have much opportunity for sql injection. Apart from that adapting the code to mysqli is trivial